# How to re-compile NM0.9 with enabled wimax?

Tags: 11.04, 12.04, network-manager

I found that the new Ubuntu comes with the Network Manager 0.9, but without the enabled wimax support. Please, give some advices how to re-compile it with --enable-wimax features. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, quite simple:

```
sudo apt-get source network-manager=0.9
sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager=0.9
```

Afterwards, we have to extract the archive network-manager_0.9.1.90.orig.tar.bz2 or another one depending on the version.

Compile with parameters:

```
$ ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-wimax --with-distro=debian --enable-ppp --enable-polkit --with-udev-dir=/etc/udev --with-dbus-sys-dir=/etc/dbus-1 --with-pppd-plugin-dir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager --with-resolvconf --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/etc/systemd --with-dhcpcd=yes
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

Of course, you need to have the wimax service and stack installed, pls, see the [linuxwimax.org](http://www.linuxwimax.org).

That's it. Should work, at least for my Intel Centrino 6250 it works greatly.

PS My recommendation to Canonical is to include the option *--enable-wimax* as default.

Comment: +1 - well done - however, canonical cannot enable this by default due to wimax restricted licensing which is not compatible with GPL

Comment: ehmmm, it's a pity, but I can add that there's no wimax stack deb package as well (!!!) even in restricted drivers.

Comment: I decided to downgrade to 11.04 due to a lot of bugs and issues. While trying to compile nm0.9 with wimax I receive the error:

Answer (score -1):

To get the driver for Wimax installed, just type the following in the terminal:

To open Terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Type in the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install madwimax
```

Comment: It works only for Samsung, but not for Intel cards.