# "configure: error: Intel WiMAX SDK is required " error when recompiling Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, compiling

I tried to to recompile network manager in [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/75934/42879) but did not succeeded.

Can you explain me how can I install wimax tools? Or tell me what is wrong with my installation?

I installed wimax tools successfully from [this source](https://github.com/ago/wimax-tools), but when I am trying to compile network manager I get this error:

```
...
checking for QT... no
checking for LIBNL1... no
checking for LIBNL2... no
checking for LIBNL3... yes
checking for UUID... yes
checking for IWMX_SDK... no
configure: error: Intel WiMAX SDK is required
```

Comment: You may have to point configure to the headers? `./configure --wimax=/usr/local/wimax` or wherever the headers are located. Try `./configure --help | less` to glean the correct switch. Also, if wimax libs are installed in a non-default location, you may have to configure the ld path and run `ldconfig`. The basic meaning of the error is that configure cannot locate the software it needs to compile.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that WiMAX support in network-manager is written against some specific SDK from Intel, which they seem to have dropped the ball on, as I can't seem to find a link to download it anywhere, and linuxwimax.org is dead. In order to compile network-manager against wimax-tools instead, it would need some work to look for that library, and match the API it uses.