# driver for wimax usb modem huawei BM338

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install driver for a Wimax modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102790/cannot-install-driver-for-a-wimax-modem)

List item

I use ubuntu 11.04 but wimax usb huawei dont run in ubuntu. 
I cant anyway connect internet.
please help me?do you put deb file for me?

Comment: after a bit of google-ing...sprint posted a developer pack here: http://developer.sprint.com/getDocument.do?docId=101032 and some fellow documented the process pretty well here: http://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID3/71759.html  google translate got it to readable english.

Comment: They got it to build for 11.10 on x64 by commenting out 2 things